# Google Speech To Text Api using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, linker-errors, google-speech-api

I am using GoogleSpeechRecongnization api within my project for Speech To Text. 
I have copied all required files and installed pod from [sample of Google for Speech To Text](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Objective-C/) Api. Also copied these 2 files AudioController, SpeechRecognitionService from the Sample Code to implement the feature.
Now when I compiled my code, I received errors as in attached image.

While same steps and files are working perfectly in demo app with the custom interface, created by me.

[image]

Please help me to fix these in my main project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check demo project ***supported architectures*** in ***build settings***...
I think you need to add missing architecture in your ***build settings***

Maybe it's in ***your project*** and maybe it's in the ***Pods*** project

Comment: I have already checked that, architecture are same as in Google Demo and my own created demo as well. My demo is also working fine, but received error in main project.

Comment: Check the Pods project in the correct target build settings

Answer (score 0):

The **SpeechRecognitionService** require google service to be linked which lies in the **google folder** of the sample Project, please add that too in your project, it should be working..

See where is google folder here

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: I already have this folder, without this folder, pod installation failed with errors

Comment: Check the Build Settings of Sample Project and look for Library Path or Header Path match with your I am sure you will find something @Surjeet